# Cant remove files from Windows disk while in Linux

Tags: mount

so i kinda messed up windows and now my pin isnt available so i cant login. im trying to delete ngc folder while in linux but it wont delete. tried remounting the system as rw but when i try to rm -r ngc it says its not empty. checked for fuse files but there arent any. i cant remove any files from the windows disk anyway so its not just the ngc folder. anyone has any idea?[this is what i get when i tree ngc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nsshI.png)
so the whole problem is i cant log into windows because of the pin so other solutions besides writing on the disk are welcome!!
thank you

Comment: Shut down windows (no hibernate, no fast boot) and try again

Comment: yeah i read something about that! the thing is i cant disable fast boot because i cant login into windows :( is there a way to do it without logging?

Answer (score -1):

This seems to be a problem with windows, it also happened to me, i couldn't delete or modify any files in ntfs partitions with windows installed. It may happen because of windows fast boot option. My guess is it makes disk think it is in use after shutdown/reboot. Try disabling it in windows control panel. Since i changed that option, drive was always at read/write  state.

Edit: Since you can't login on windows, try using some usb external windows live media, something like hiren's boot or sergei strelec and use some program to remove the account password... if it is not local (microsoft account) i don't know if it will work...

Comment: i cant login into windows so i cant disable fast boot :( is there a way to do it without logging?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know windows. Ask the windows guys